# Jquery on scroll loading is not working (does not update index)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm struggling to send an incremented number to my PHP script to load more content. At the moment this script is fully working when I tested, but the number that is incremented by the jQuery when the page is scrolled does not send it to the PHP script. Therefore, the PHP script executes the same content on page scrolling. Could someone help me fix it?

Comment: not a solution, but just to let you know.. `document.getElementById("id")` can always be replaced by the jquery $("#id"). If you want the value you can do `$("#id").val()` and if you want the innerhtml you can do `$("#id").html()`

Comment: as aa beginner to jquery i didnt realy get your answer ? Can you please help me to make this script working ?

Comment: i am still looking into the script. Regarding what i said before, for instance: instead of writing `document.getElementById("row_no").value` you can write `$("#row_no").val()`. It would give the same with lesser code.

Comment: also please add php in your tags

Comment: In which tag should i add php ??

Comment: i meant in this stack overflow question where you have set the tags as "javascript" "jquery" and "ajax" if you could also set php people related to php would look at this too

Comment: it is not posible for me. thats why i add the script code like this above.

This code didnt still work. It is same like before. it doesnt update the number in php

Comment: I meant the tags shown below. Never mind I have edited the question and added it. I have also posted an answer. Let me know if it works. It's been years since i coded in php... not sure of my syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you have sent an ajax post request with the data "getresult". However you have not yet taken this data in your php. Since this code is sent with the key "getresult", in php you can retrieve it by using `$_POST["getresult"]`

However since this parameter is optional, you can always use a variable like:

> $limit = 0;

You can then alter this variable IF the post variable is present

> if (isset($_POST["getresult"])) $limit = $_POST["getresult"];

Finally make sure that you use this variable inside the post instead of the 0

> mysql_query("select `AdName`, `Photo1name` from tbl_name limit ".$limit.",10")